# Why does getPreventDefault() work but defaultPrevented doesn't?

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm working on a Firefox extension, and I keep seeing the following warning:

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.

However, for what I'm trying to do it seems that `defaultPrevented` doesn't work, while `getPreventDefault()` does.  For a simplified code snippet, here's what I put into my Firefox browser scratchpad while running in the `Browser` context:

```
window.addEventListener('fooEvent', function (event) { 
    console.log('fooEvent has fired');
    event.preventDefault();
}, true, true);
```

So then in my browser console (the one I get when hitting Shift+Ctrl+k) I run the following code:

```
e = document.createEvent('Event');
e.initEvent('fooEvent', true, true);
document.dispatchEvent(e);
console.log('after dispatch', e.defaultPrevented, e.getPreventDefault());
```

I can see the `fooEvent has fired` message in my Javascript console, so I know the event was caught.  But I see the message `after dispatch false true` which indicates that `defaultPrevented` is still false while `getPreventDefault()` is correctly returning true.  But Firefox still displays the deprecation warning!

I'd like to avoid using a deprecated API call because I don't want a Firefox upgrade to break my extension.  (There's an [open ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691151) for the deprecated API call to be removed, though it looks like it'll probably be awhile before it's completed.)  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this?: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=985988

Comment: @Nile: I'm seeing this behavior in Firefox 29, where that bug has already been fixed.  I also just confirmed the fix locally by running the snippet in that ticket to confirm that ``defaultPrevented`` is ``true`` in the alert message.

Comment: @EliCourtwright: No, that bug report states they didn't fix it in FF29?

Comment: @Bergi: The fix was backported to Firefox 29 (`status-firefox29: verified`). Was landed on the branches in comment #16.

Comment: @nmaier: I thought `verified` meant something like "confirmed" or "reproducable", not "fixed"? Correct me if I'm wrong. And comment #19 says the fix didn't make it into 29Beta, I haven't checked the VCS about backports though.

Comment: @Bergi nah, verified means "verified fixed". Confirmed bugs are "new" instead of "unconfirmed" and statuses usually "affected".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this in Firefox 30 and Nightly.

What you have discovered here seems to be a genuine bug when it comes to handling synthetic content events from privileged code.

To answer your question: You don't seem to do anything wrong; the browser is.
Use `getDefaultPrevented()` for the time being and while it is still available.
You can feature-detect (and hope that `.defaultPrevented` will be fixed before `.getPreventDefault()` is removed):

```
var dp = "getPreventDefault" in e ?
  e.getPreventDefault() :
  e.defaultPrevented;
```

As the one who discovered this bug, please [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) and block it against https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691151

It would be great if you provided the new bug URI in a comment or something. If you don't want to file yourself, please say so and I will file it for you.

*Edit*

Another way to deal with it is to use the result of `dispatchEvent()`. Apparantly the mozilla folks *forgot* to break it, too.

> The return value of dispatchEvent indicates whether any of the listeners which handled the event called preventDefault. If preventDefault was called the value is false, else the value is true.

[from: DOM-Level-2-Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent)

```
e = document.createEvent('Event');
e.initEvent('fooEvent', true, true);
if (document.dispatchEvent(e)) {
  // Execute default action
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I've filed a bug as you suggested and made the other ticket a blocker against it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1024488

Comment: Edit: `dispatchEvent` return value.

Comment: Interesting.  I already implemented (and tested) your original suggestion about checking for the presence of ``getPreventDefault`` and then using that if it exists and otherwise falling back on ``defaultPrevented``.  I didn't realize that ``dispatchEvent`` had that return value, and I'll keep that in mind next time I'm working on that code or doing anything similar.  Thanks!